# Can contact information from my lock screen be available without a password on startup?

Tags: lock-screens, boot, samsung-galaxy-s-9

I just got a Samsung Galaxy S9 with Android 10. In my current configuration, I have observed this rough state machine as it starts up.

[image: Approximate state machine on startup.]

The `Settings > Lock screen > Contact information` is a great feature. However, I see no way to ever see that message in any of the grey states without the password. Is it possible to configure Android so that the contact information is accessible from any state, or at least from powered-off or out-of-battery, without disabling all security features?

Comment: https://www.gihosoft.com/android-recovery/add-emergency-info-android-lock-screen.html

Comment: Looks like your device uses full disk encryption (FDE). For that encryption Google decided to use a seperate miniOS for entering the boot password. Therefore this miniOS is independent of the main OS and can't be configured at all (except for the required password). Therefore your lock screen info is not available in this mode. Modern devices use a different encryption mode (FBE) where the device directly boots Android up to the lock screen. Changing the encryption mode is only possible with root and a custom ROM.

Comment: @Robert Android 10 forces FBE

Comment: @alecxs If the device comes with Android 10 FBE is the default. But the S9 was upgraded to Android 10 and as far as I remember the encryption type does not change on an upgrade.

Comment: It came with 10; this makes a lot of sense, but is a bit wierd. I could presumably make an emergency call, which I think connects with my cell carrier, something much more difficult then simply modifying a local text field?

Comment: i am using android 7 and i can reach emergency information as submenu from emergency dialer

Comment: @alecxs so "emergency call," contrary to implications, does not phone 911 instantly? I can press this safely?

Comment: @alecxs That is only relevant for the initial Android version a device is launched with. Galaxy S9 was launched with Android 8 and upgraded to 10. See [Samsung statement on FBD/FDE](https://support.samsungknox.com/hc/en-us/articles/360039577713-File-based-encryption-FBE-and-full-disk-encryption-FDE-)

Comment: in my country 911 is not a valid number

Comment: @Robert thx for clarifying! looks like Samsung is "violating" android guidelines (and a proof that indeed android 10 is able to run on FDE)

Comment: @Neil pressing "emergency call" button will show the dialer where the user can input any emergency number (not only 911, but also 110 or other valid emergency numbers on the user's country), or additionally accessing emergency info.

Answer (score 0):

The July 1, 2020 security update also adds the contact info in the state "Your phone is encryted . . . " Simply downloading and installing this 1GB update makes all of the state machine blue.